# Which notable Bitcoin-related sites offer referral rewards?

Tags: websites, earnings

TradeHill used to offer a referral bonus when you got other people to sign up with your link, and there are a couple other sites that offer similar rewards for referrals. Which notable Bitcoin-related websites offer such rewards?

Comment: Bitcoin.de has such a program, I believe: You get a cut of their fee for all trades by users you brought in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is a comprehensive list of websites for getting free bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/where-is-a-comprehensive-list-of-websites-for-getting-free-bitcoins)

Answer (score 2):

Between TradeHill, Bitcoin7 and a couple others the offering of affiliate rewards ended up spawning a spamfest.  Fortunately, TradeHill added terms and conditions that included no spamming and withheld commissions to spammers and the problem mostly went away.

Camp BX apparently is one that offers a referral.  10% discount on trading fees for them and 10% commission for you.
After login, click on "My Profile" (or https://campbx.com/in/userinfo.php )
then scroll down to Affiliate Program Link.

Others:

- http://clients.microtronix-tech.com/aff.php

Answer (score 1):

- [Strike Sapphire](https://strikesapphire.com/) is a casino offering poker freerolls and various table games and slots.  You receive $20 each time one of your referrals makes their first Bitcoin deposit.
- [BitMadness](http://www.bitmadness.com/) is a basketball result prediction game with Bitcoin prizes.  If you refer somebody and they win a prize, you get 10% of what they win.

Comment: Is strike sapphire even legal?

Comment: It seems they go to great lengths to block players from the USA.  Not that that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [Bitcoin minefield](http://minefield.bitcoinlab.org/) which is a fast paced gambling site.

Answer (score 1):

LocalBitcoins.com has affiliate program:

http://localbitcoins.com/affiliate/

More about it here:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1izazv/become_an_affiliate_for_localbitcoins_and_earn/

Answer (score 0):

Hashr.org has an affiliate program "HASHR.8" (hashrate) that gives it's affiliates 8% of every sale they bring to the site.  Payable in Bitcoin or Litecoin

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin casino [SatoshiBet](https://satoshibet.com) has an affiliate program that offers 25% of the house edge of all bets made by players you refer, forever.

Joining their affiliate is pretty easy, just go to https://satoshibet.com/affiliate and start sharing your referral link.

Example: A player clicks your link and decides to play roulette. The house edge of roulette is 2.7%. Say the player bets 1 BTC on black. You will then receive (1BTC*0.027)*0.25 = 0.00675 BTC for that single bet (no matter the outcome for the player). If he bets again, you will get another 0.00675 BTC, and so on and so forth.. If you have a few players this can really add up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The best referral scheme I have seen so far is the Bitcoin wallet [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/).

[Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/) is a cloud-based Bitcoin wallet that allows users to buy and sell bitcoins with a US bank account, send and receive bitcoins with an email address, and accept bitcoin payments as a merchant.

The scheme offers 0.01 BTC to the referrer and the referee upon completion of a 1 BTC buy or sell transaction within 90 days of the referee joining the site. The program works even if the user closes the browser and comes back later. So long as they click your link the referral program will work so long as they join within 90 days.

Additionally, links are provided to share on your Facebook, Twitter and Google+ accounts which will also generate referrals.

You can also invite your Gmail contacts through the site generating further referrals.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 nice affiliate programs:

[CoinPoker](http://coinpoker.io/affiliate-program/) - officially licensed to conduct online gaming operations by the government of Curacao. That guarantees that your funds are safe.

[BitCasino](http://bitcasino.io/affiliate-program/) - Generous payout structure let you earn up to 50% commission on every player

Answer (score -1):

The [MPEx](http://polimedia.us/mpex) securities exchange offers 5BTC reward if referral account is mentioned while creating new account. MPEx broker [CoinBr.com](https://coinbr.com) has referral program, too.

Comment: mpex has a 30BTC signing up fee. Which at the current rate =~1395€. I don't think it's worth mentioning it in any context save from bashing it.