# Where is a comprehensive list of websites for getting free bitcoins?

Tags: services, websites

Up till now I know two websites where one can get free bitcoins:

- http://www.bitvisitor.com/
- https://freebitcoins.appspot.com
- http://freebitco.in
- http://takefreebitcoin.com/

Is there a comprehensive list of all such websites available somewhere?

Comment: Counterpoint to this question: [Do faucets actually work?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12923/do-faucets-actually-work)

Comment: -1 "Free bitcoins". 0.00000041 to 0.00000102 BTC every five minutes is less than a dollarcent per hour. I don't think sites like that should be promoted further.

Comment: @Murch I only added them because someone created a referal edit with these links. Also you would not expect to earn for your next Ferrari by clicking links or do you? Based on my thoughts these get free bitcoins sites are just to get you started with bitcoins and not to get rich by mouse clicking

Comment: 1. They shouldn't be part of the question in the first place. 2. The business model of such sites is exploitative and/or scammy. 3. It's basically impossible to earn enough to fuel even a single transaction on such a site thus they are at best a bad first impression for Bitcoin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constantly updated list: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=90718.0

> Free Bitcoin sites:

The Bitcoin faucet.
One time payout per Google account. Explanation available at the site.

Daily Bitcoins.
Can be used once an hour now, and not just once a day.

CoinAd.com.
Can be used once an hour with registration.

Bitcoin Addict

Bitcoiner

Bunny Run.
See here for more info.

Free bitcoins - netlookup.se

Nakabot's Bitcoin Faucet
(Tor hidden service) NakaBot pays out a portion of its winnings in 0.001 increments.

Free BitCoin Daily Scratchcard

kickme.to/goxkeygen
MtGox account needed to redeem the code one receives.

bitcoinpixels.com
0.01 BTC free when signing up to betfair. See here for more info.

memorydealers
Learn how here.

Omnicoins
Learn how here.

cointicket.org

BitCrate *

bitcoins.so *
Roll dice : same numbers - win 0.01

Paperco.in faucet *
Scan a QR code to reveal a MtGox code for 0.0007 BTC.

---

### Gambling sites that give out free bitcoins ( freerolls etc. ) after you join

Dragon's Tale
A casino site, but gives out small amounts for free that you can use to gamble with or withdraw to your own Bitcoin wallet.

Seals with Clubs
Seals has a free poker tournament every hour with a .05BTC prize. There are larger free tournaments from time to time.
See here for more info.

Strike Sapphire
See here for more info.

---

### Not exactly Free but popular "earn" Bitcoin sites

BitVisitor
Earn Bitcoins for visiting websites

CoinTube.TV
Earn Bitcoins for watching TV

Comment: Care to copy the list over in case the website is no longer available in the future? Also, please remove the unnecessary lllllls.

Comment: there is also this forum topic https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=74046 which has much the same content but some of the replies contain links that may not be in the forum topic linked above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out this site: http://earnfreebitcoins.com

> EarnFreeBitcoins.com is a website in which you earn small amounts of
>   Bitcoins in exchange for visiting websites for a designated period of
>   time. You may be required to spend anywhere from one minute, up to
>   five minutes or more on the sponsored website. You must spend the full
>   amount of required time on the website in order to recieve payment.

Answer (score 1):

http://skude.se/BTC/ provides links to a number of websites that provide free bitcoins, but generally doesn't include sites it doesn't get a referral bonus from. It also provides a timer that helps you determine when you can revisit each site to collect more.

Another site providing a good list in a readable format is here:
http://bitcoiner.net/list

Answer (score 1):

[www.FreeBitcoinSites.com](http://www.freebitcoinsites.com) and [www.squidoo.com/freebitcoins](http://www.squidoo.com/freebitcoins) are a couple of good resources for places to get free bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

And here you get paid up to 4 mBTC for viewing websites for 5 minutes http://www.bitvisitor.com

Comment: can you clarify how exactly one can get coins here?

Answer (score -1):

Most of those websites don't give free bitcoins anymore. The only updated daily list I've been able to find is at the end of any post of the blog http://thebitcoinmaster.blogspot.com