# Where to earn bitcoins?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, earnings

I know that you can mine bitcoins and that you can buy them, but what about places where you can earn them by doing a bit of work?

I've only heard of http://bfg.swfchan.com/ where you get BTC for linking to the site.

Are there any other places where you can earn bitcoins?

I tried to find a list of such places but I can't find one. Is there such a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is a comprehensive list of websites for getting free bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/where-is-a-comprehensive-list-of-websites-for-getting-free-bitcoins)

Answer (score 2):

1. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Jobs
2. http://workforbitcoin.com
3. http://www.btcworkers.com
4. http://bitgigs.com
5. http://www.rugatu.com
6. http://www.bitcoinerr.com
7. http://www.reddit.com/r/Jobs4bitcoins
8. http://coinworker.com
9. http://bittask.com

All of these boards are ugly, though. Wait for StackExchange to start using Bitcoins.

Comment: Thanks! Though three of those URLs are dead (not loading at the moment or suspended) and one is a duplicate (redirect to another). I'd love to see more if there are any.

Comment: Welcome to http://en.bitcoin.it wiki. Please, post what you found.

Comment: What do you mean? Where on the bitcoin wiki can you find where to earn coins?

Answer (score 2):

Got to [Earn Bitcoins](http://earn-bitcoins.com/). It's a website I compiled about this topic. All possible ways to earn Bitcoins are listed there. I will also constantly be adding links, so it's just a start right now.