# Why would someone use a BTC faucet if it pays 200 satoshi every 15 minutes?

Tags: faucets

I've seen many people talking about faucets but why would a sane person do it to get less than 1 cent every 15 minutes???

Comment: related: [Do faucets actually work?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12923/5406)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reasons. First, you may simply want to test some functionality with some faucet coins. Second, you may think it's an excellent investment. Third, you may want to pay for some micro-transaction.