# Who is hosting my bitcoin address?

Tags: lost-wallet

Well I set up a few different bitcoin wallets one night and somehow I have one of my faucets set up to send money to a wallet that I dont remember setting up. I have the bitcoin address but I don't know if its a coinbase, coinmama, torwallet or what? Any ideas how to find out how to log into it?

Answer (score 2):

No way to know.  Bitcoin addresses are created by a random generation process, and the address itself shouldn't contain any information associating it with the site where it was created.  If it did, that would weaken your privacy.

The wallet site should have offered you the option to back up your private key, so you might look for those keys somewhere on your computer.  Otherwise, if you don't know the site and have the required password / passphrase / whatever, you cannot get those coins.

Fortunately, faucets provide such a minuscule amount of bitcoin that you surely haven't lost much (see [Do faucets actually work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12923/do-faucets-actually-work)).  So it's probably not worth your time to do anything other than just start again.  This time, make a backup of your private keys.